# Multiple unix pipes not working

Tags: unix, pipe, fifo, netcat

This first pipeline works fine (printing "c"):

```
echo "a" | sed 's/a/b/' | sed 's/b/c/'
```

This one does not do what I expect (nothing gets printed when I feed an "a" into my fifo ):

```
mkfifo fifo;
cat fifo | sed 's/a/b/' | sed 's/b/c/'
```

However, if I remove the second "sed" command from the latter pipeline, I do get a "b" printed. I think my understanding of pipes and redirects must be too simplistic. **Can someone explain to me how to fix the 2nd case** so that I can run two successive commands on the contents of the fifo?

(note this isn't a problem specific to fifo, the same behavior occurs with netcat too. I posted a similar question about netcat but got no answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffering. `sed` is changing it's buffering depending on whether the output is a tty or not. When you have two sed's, the first determines it's output is not a tty so it is buffering. So when you have:

```
cat fifo | sed 's/a/b'
```

sed is not buffering as it's output is to a tty so you see the data but when you have:

```
cat fifo | sed 's/a/b' | sed 's/c/d'
```

the first sed is buffering the data. Depending on the specific sed you are running, there are different ways to disable buffering. GNU sed has the `--unbuffered` option while BSD sed has the `-l` option to switch to line buffering.

Comment: It works! `cat fifo | sed --unbuffered 's/a/b/' | sed 's/b/c/'`

Comment: There are also issues with how the 'a' gets written to the FIFO.  With the `cat fifo`, another process must be writing to the FIFO, presumably from another terminal window, but because the `cat` still has the FIFO open, there is no EOF.  By contrast, with `echo`, the first line is echoed and then the first `sed` gets EOF, so it flushes its output (and exits), and so does the second `sed`.