# pipes are clogged - one shell pipe works, but two don't

Tags: pipe, buffer

How to I get this to work? (Why does it not work?)

```
iostat -n9 -w 5 | gcut -c 14-20,34-40,54-60 | perl -p -e 's/(\d\.\d)\d/\1 /g'
```

By contrast,

```
iostat -n9      | gcut -c 14-20,34-40,54-60 | perl -p -e 's/(\d\.\d)\d/\1 /g'
```

works fine.

(Similarly, if each command is a letter,
`a | b | c` and `a | c | b` don't work,
but `a | b` and `a | c`  work fine.

This is on macOS, if that matters.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `[g]stdbuf` for less buffering.  This works:

```
iostat -n9 -w 5 | gstdbuf --output=L gcut -c 14-20,34-40,54-60 | perl -p -e 's/(\d\.\d)\d/\1 /g' 
                  ------------------
```

Buffering was the problem.  [Multiple unix pipes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112713/multiple-unix-pipes-not-working) got me on the right track.  There's no mention of gstdbuf 'round here, so I thought this would be useful.

Which leads to another question: Why does it work with gcut but not with cut - even if I minimize buffering? :

```
gstdbuf --input=0 --output=0 iostat -n9 -w 5 | gstdbuf --input=0 --output=0 cut -c 14-20,34-40,54-60 | gstdbuf --input=0 --output=0 perl -p -e 's/(\d\.\d)\d/\1 /g'
```

Comment: (Yeah, if starting over, I'd do everything but rewrite iostat itself in perl, with variables and proper rounding... but it's already a series of aliases, functions, perl and pipes... ugly...and it works well. )